# Why my reducer doesn't work when I click a button?

Tags: react-redux

So I've just started learning redux, and I created a simple reducer which adds a number when you click on the button.
It looks like this:

```
const defaultState = {
    cash: 5,
}

export const cashReducer = (state = defaultState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_CASHER':
                return{...state, cash: state.cash + action.payload}
        case 'GET_CASHER':
            return{...state, cash: state.cash - action.payload}

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

index.js file:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { cashReducer } from './cashReducer';
import { customReducer} from './customReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    cash: cashReducer,
    custom: customReducer,
})

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());
```

App.js file:

```
const App = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const cash = useSelector(state => state.cash.cash);

    const addCash = (cash) =>{
        dispatch({type: 'ADD_CASH', payload: cash});
    }

    const getCash = (cash) =>{
        dispatch({type: 'GET_CASH', payload: cash});
    }

    return(
        <div className="main">
            <h1 style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{cash}</h1>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => addCash(Number(prompt()))}>add cash</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => getCash(Number(prompt()))}>get cash</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And buttons look like this:
[image]

So when I click on the button it should receive a number through the prompt and add it to the current number. But when I click both of the buttons nothing happens.
Everything is pretty simple, so I can't figure out what could be the problem here.

Comment: Your routes are defined as `ADD_CASHER` and `GET_CASHER`. Your dispatches call `ADD_CASH` and `GET_CASH`.

Comment: omg, i must've gone blind, haha, thank you! and i was wondering what i could do wrong